# MySQL claims that a built-in function "does not exist."

Tags: mysql

Tell me what's wrong in these two queries?

```
SELECT * FROM `product_description` WHERE CHAR_LENGTH (description) > 250
SELECT * FROM `product_description` WHERE LENGTH (description) > 250
```

They return these error

```
Function table.name CHAR_LENGTH does not exist
Function table.name LENGTH does not exist
```

both functions seems not to work... what is going on ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe it is [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/functions.html) which causes the issue

By default there must be no whitespace between a function name and the parenthesis following it. This helps the MySQL parser distinguish between function calls and references to tables or columns that happen to have the same name as a function. However, spaces around function arguments are permitted.

Comment: Yup seems to be a space related problem. Thanks